# Theano cannot find lstdc++

Tags: python, c++, g++, anaconda, theano

I used anaconda2 to install mingw and libpython, afterwards I test run the Theano by doing import theano on the IDLE, unfortunately I am experiencing an error telling me several files are not found.

I went to the file path C:\Anaconda2\MinGW\x86_64-w64-mingw32\lib and I found that there are indeed no such file named -lstdc++ but there is libstdc++.a, libmingw32.a,libgcc_s.a and the rest, there is only one file that I cannot find and that is lgcc.a or libgcc.a.

My suspicion is that I need to uninstall my Theano and and reinstall the Bleeding edge version, but I would like to ask can this be solve even without installing the Bleeding Edge version? Or is this really needed?

Here is the traceback:

```
   Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
        import theano
      File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\theano-0.9.0.dev2-py2.7.egg\theano\__init__.py", line 70, in <module>
        from theano.compile import (
      File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\theano-0.9.0.dev2-py2.7.egg\theano\compile\__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
        from theano.compile.function_module import *
      File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\theano-0.9.0.dev2-py2.7.egg\theano\compile\function_module.py", line 21, in <module>
        import theano.compile.mode
      File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\theano-0.9.0.dev2-py2.7.egg\theano\compile\mode.py", line 12, in <module>
        import theano.gof.vm
      File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\theano-0.9.0.dev2-py2.7.egg\theano\gof\vm.py", line 654, in <module>
        from . import lazylinker_c
      File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\theano-0.9.0.dev2-py2.7.egg\theano\gof\lazylinker_c.py", line 127, in <module>
        preargs=args)
      File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\theano-0.9.0.dev2-py2.7.egg\theano\gof\cmodule.py", line 2299, in compile_str
        (status, compile_stderr.replace('\n', '. ')))
    Exception: Compilation failed (return status=1): c:/anaconda2/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.7.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:\Python27\libs/libpython27.a when searching for -lpython27
    . c:/anaconda2/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.7.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible c:/anaconda2/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.7.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libstdc++.dll.a when searching for -lstdc++
    . c:/anaconda2/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.7.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible c:/anaconda2/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.7.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libstdc++.a when searching for -lstdc++
    . c:/anaconda2/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.7.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible c:/anaconda2/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.7.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib\libstdc++.a when searching for -lstdc++
    . c:/anaconda2/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.7.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible c:/anaconda2/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.7.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libstdc++.dll.a when searching for -lstdc++
    . c:/anaconda2/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.7.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible c:/anaconda2/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.7.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libstdc++.a when searching for -lstdc++
    . c:/anaconda2/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.7.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lstdc++
    . c:/anaconda2/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.7.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lmingw32
    . c:/anaconda2/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.7.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible c:/anaconda2/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.7.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libgcc_s.a when searching for -lgcc_s
    . c:/anaconda2/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.7.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible c:/anaconda2/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.7.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib\libgcc_s.a when searching for -lgcc_s
    . c:/anaconda2/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.7.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible c:/anaconda2/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.7.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libgcc_s.a when searching for -lgcc_s
    . c:/anaconda2/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.7.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lgcc_s
    . c:/anaconda2/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.7.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible c:/anaconda2/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.7.0/libgcc.a when searching for -lgcc
    . c:/anaconda2/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.7.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible c:/anaconda2/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.7.0\libgcc.a when searching for -lgcc
    . c:/anaconda2/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.7.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible c:/anaconda2/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.7.0/libgcc.a when searching for -lgcc
    . c:/anaconda2/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.7.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lgcc
    . c:/anaconda2/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.7.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible c:/anaconda2/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.7.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libmoldname.a when searching for -lmoldname
    . c:/anaconda2/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.7.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible c:/anaconda2/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.7.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib\libmoldname.a when searching for -lmoldname
    . c:/anaconda2/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.7.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible c:/anaconda2/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.7.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libmoldname.a when searching for -lmoldname
    . c:/anaconda2/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.7.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lmoldname
    . c:/anaconda2/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.7.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible c:/anaconda2/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.7.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libmingwex.a when searching for -lmingwex
    . c:/anaconda2/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.7.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible c:/anaconda2/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.7.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib\libmingwex.a when searching for -lmingwex
    . c:/anaconda2/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.7.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible c:/anaconda2/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.7.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libmingwex.a when searching for -lmingwex
    . c:/anaconda2/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.7.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lmingwex
    . c:/anaconda2/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.7.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible c:/anaconda2/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.7.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libmsvcrt.a when searching for -lmsvcrt
    . c:/anaconda2/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.7.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible c:/anaconda2/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.7.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib\libmsvcrt.a when searching for -lmsvcrt
    . c:/anaconda2/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.7.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible c:/anaconda2/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.7.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libmsvcrt.a when searching for -lmsvcrt
    . c:/anaconda2/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.7.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lmsvcrt
    . c:/anaconda2/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.7.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible c:/anaconda2/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.7.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libadvapi32.a when searching for -ladvapi32
    . c:/anaconda2/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.7.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible c:/anaconda2/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.7.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib\libadvapi32.a when searching for -ladvapi32
    . c:/anaconda2/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.7.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible c:/anaconda2/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.7.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libadvapi32.a when searching for -ladvapi32
    . c:/anaconda2/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.7.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -ladvapi32
    . c:/anaconda2/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.7.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible c:/anaconda2/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.7.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libshell32.a when searching for -lshell32
    . c:/anaconda2/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.7.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible c:/anaconda2/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.7.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib\libshell32.a when searching for -lshell32
    . c:/anaconda2/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.7.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible c:/anaconda2/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.7.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libshell32.a when searching for -lshell32
    . c:/anaconda2/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.7.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lshell32
    . c:/anaconda2/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.7.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible c:/anaconda2/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.7.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libuser32.a when searching for -luser32
    . c:/anaconda2/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.7.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible c:/anaconda2/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.7.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib\libuser32.a when searching for -luser32
    . c:/anaconda2/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.7.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible c:/anaconda2/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.7.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libuser32.a when searching for -luser32
    . c:/anaconda2/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.7.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -luser32
    . c:/anaconda2/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.7.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible c:/anaconda2/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.7.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libkernel32.a when searching for -lkernel32
    . c:/anaconda2/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.7.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible c:/anaconda2/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.7.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib\libkernel32.a when searching for -lkernel32
    . c:/anaconda2/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.7.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible c:/anaconda2/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.7.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libkernel32.a when searching for -lkernel32
    . c:/anaconda2/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.7.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lkernel32
    . c:/anaconda2/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.7.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lmingw32
    . c:/anaconda2/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.7.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible c:/anaconda2/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.7.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libgcc_s.a when searching for -lgcc_s
    . c:/anaconda2/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.7.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible c:/anaconda2/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.7.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib\libgcc_s.a when searching for -lgcc_s
    . c:/anaconda2/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.7.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible c:/anaconda2/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.7.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libgcc_s.a when searching for -lgcc_s
    . c:/anaconda2/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.7.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lgcc_s
    . c:/anaconda2/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.7.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible c:/anaconda2/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.7.0/libgcc.a when searching for -lgcc
    . c:/anaconda2/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.7.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible c:/anaconda2/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.7.0\libgcc.a when searching for -lgcc
    . c:/anaconda2/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.7.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible c:/anaconda2/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.7.0/libgcc.a when searching for -lgcc
    . c:/anaconda2/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.7.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lgcc
    . c:/anaconda2/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.7.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible c:/anaconda2/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.7.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libmoldname.a when searching for -lmoldname
    . c:/anaconda2/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.7.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible c:/anaconda2/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.7.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib\libmoldname.a when searching for -lmoldname
    . c:/anaconda2/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.7.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible c:/anaconda2/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.7.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libmoldname.a when searching for -lmoldname
    . c:/anaconda2/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.7.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lmoldname
    . c:/anaconda2/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.7.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible c:/anaconda2/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.7.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libmingwex.a when searching for -lmingwex
    . c:/anaconda2/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.7.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible c:/anaconda2/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.7.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib\libmingwex.a when searching for -lmingwex
    . c:/anaconda2/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.7.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible c:/anaconda2/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.7.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libmingwex.a when searching for -lmingwex
    . c:/anaconda2/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.7.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lmingwex
    . c:/anaconda2/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.7.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible c:/anaconda2/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.7.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libmsvcrt.a when searching for -lmsvcrt
    . c:/anaconda2/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.7.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible c:/anaconda2/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.7.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib\libmsvcrt.a when searching for -lmsvcrt
    . c:/anaconda2/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.7.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible c:/anaconda2/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.7.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libmsvcrt.a when searching for -lmsvcrt
    . c:/anaconda2/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.7.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lmsvcrt
    . collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Following the reinsallation of Anaconda on a 32bit windows I experience the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    import theano
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\theano-0.9.0.dev2-py2.7.egg\theano\__init__.py", line 70, in <module>
    from theano.compile import (
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\theano-0.9.0.dev2-py2.7.egg\theano\compile\__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
    from theano.compile.function_module import *
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\theano-0.9.0.dev2-py2.7.egg\theano\compile\function_module.py", line 21, in <module>
    import theano.compile.mode
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\theano-0.9.0.dev2-py2.7.egg\theano\compile\mode.py", line 12, in <module>
    import theano.gof.vm
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\theano-0.9.0.dev2-py2.7.egg\theano\gof\vm.py", line 654, in <module>
    from . import lazylinker_c
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\theano-0.9.0.dev2-py2.7.egg\theano\gof\lazylinker_c.py", line 127, in <module>
    preargs=args)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\theano-0.9.0.dev2-py2.7.egg\theano\gof\cmodule.py", line 2299, in compile_str
    (status, compile_stderr.replace('\n', '. ')))
Exception: Compilation failed (return status=1): C:\Python27\libs/libpython27.a(dmmes00245.o):(.idata$7+0x0): undefined reference to `__head_C__build27_cpython_PCBuild_libpython27_a'
. C:\Python27\libs/libpython27.a(dmmes00223.o):(.idata$7+0x0): undefined reference to `__head_C__build27_cpython_PCBuild_libpython27_a'
. C:\Python27\libs/libpython27.a(dmmes00054.o):(.idata$7+0x0): undefined reference to `__head_C__build27_cpython_PCBuild_libpython27_a'
. C:\Python27\libs/libpython27.a(dmmes01026.o):(.idata$7+0x0): undefined reference to `__head_C__build27_cpython_PCBuild_libpython27_a'
. C:\Python27\libs/libpython27.a(dmmes00253.o):(.idata$7+0x0): undefined reference to `__head_C__build27_cpython_PCBuild_libpython27_a'
. C:\Python27\libs/libpython27.a(dmmes00207.o):(.idata$7+0x0): more undefined references to `__head_C__build27_cpython_PCBuild_libpython27_a' follow
. collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Answer (score 0):

The exact message given is:

```
skipping incompatible .../libstdc++.dll.a when searching for -lstdc++
etc..
```

I also see it looking for `user32` and `kernel32`, yet the toolchain is apparently configured for `x86_64-w64-mingw32`.

Are you trying to compile Theano for a 32-bit system using a 64-bit toolchain? You should check your compiler flags.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @ams, my machine is a windows 8.1 64 bit, my python is 2.7.10 32 bits, I downloaded my anaconda for windows 64 bit, I also set my Theano_Flags to blas.ldflags=-LC:\\openblas -lopenblas. Now that you mention it, I might try to reinstall anaconda for 32 bits and redo installing mingw and libpython..thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, after reinstalling mingw and libpython in Anaconda on 32bit windows, everything is solved by upgrading to the latest version. I updated mine from 2.7.10 to 2.7.12.

Note: Do not forget to place the Anaconda2 folder on your PATH in the variable environment.